# Multiplication and division of inequalities

Tags: inequality

I am preparing for my GRE and going through some quant topics and have a few doubts regarding Inequalities. This one question has got me irritated and I have been scratching my head since. The question goes as:

If $1 < a < 3$, $-2 < b < 2$ and $4 < c < 6$, then $\frac{ab}{c}$ lies between ?

I figured, since $a$ lies between 1 and 3, $b$ will cover the first inequality and $c$ shall cover the second but am not able to get past that.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Lemma: the extremum of $xy$ occurs at the boundary of $(x,y)$ domain

We can write $\begin{cases}x_m\le x\le x_M\\y_m\le y\le y_M\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}x=x_m+(x_M-x_m)\cdot t&t\in[0,1]\\y=y_m+(y_M-y_m)\cdot u&u\in[0,1]\end{cases}$

$$xy=(x_M-x_m)(y_M-y_m)\cdot tu + (x_M-x_m)y_m\cdot t + x_m(y_M-y_m)\cdot u + x_my_m$$

Annulation of $\ \nabla{xy}=(\dfrac{\partial{xy}}{\partial t},\dfrac{\partial{xy}}{\partial u})\ $ gives $\ \begin{cases}t_0=-\frac{x_m}{x_M-x_m}\\u_0=-\frac{y_m}{y_M-y_m}\end{cases}\iff (x,y)=(0,0)$

Obviously this is only possible while $x_m, y_m$ negative and $x_M,y_M$ positive, but in this case $xy=0$ is neither a minimum (since $x_my_M<0$) nor a maximum (since $x_My_M>0$).

Therefore the extremum of $xy$ occurs at the boundaries of the $[x_m,x_M]\times[y_m,y_M]$ box.

This means we have to examine the four values $\{x_my_m,\ x_my_M,\ x_My_m,\ x_My_M\}$

*Note: the case of strict inequalities does not change fundamentally the conclusion, it's just that we work with infimum and supremum instead of minimum and maximum.*

- Let solve the problem for the product $ab$

$\begin{cases}1<a<3\\-2<b<2\end{cases}\quad$ and the bounds belongs to

$\{(1\times -2),(1\times 2),(3\times -2),(3\times 2)\}=\{-2,2,-6,6\}$

Therefore we have that $$-6<ab<6$$

- Inversion of the inequality for $c$

Notice that $4<c<6$ can be rewritten $$\frac 16<\frac 1c<\frac 14$$

This is because $c\neq 0$ so we are in the region where $x\mapsto\frac 1x$ is continuous.

If $c$ was lying in an interval $I$ covering both positive and negative values, then we would have $\frac 1c\in(-\infty,+\infty)$ since $c$ could take values arbitrary close to $0^-$ and $0^+$.

- Final inequality for $\dfrac{ab}c$

$\begin{cases}-6<ab<6\\\frac 16<\frac 1c<\frac 14\end{cases}\quad$ and the bounds belongs to

$\{(-6\times \frac 16),(-6\times \frac 14),(6\times \frac 16),(6\times \frac 14)\}=\{-1,-\frac 32,1,\frac 32\}$

Therefore we have $$-\frac 32<\frac {ab}c<\frac 32$$

Comment: thanks a lot buddy for your efforts. But can you kindly provide me with a simple answer and explanation. Thanks again.

Comment: Just remember $[a<x<b]$ and $[c<y<d]$ then $\min(ac,ad,bc,bd)<xy<\max(ac,ad,bc,bd)$ and $[0<a<x<b]$ then $\frac 1b<\frac 1x<\frac 1a$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will remember it.